# Viewing and deleting partitions using the BIOS?

Tags: partitioning, bios

I have an M4A785TD-M EVO Asus motherboard which uses Asus Express Gate for its motherboard (says American Megatrends, Inc at the bottom). I activate it by pressing Del; also says Tab activates BIOS Post but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I went into this expecting to see a breakdown of the partitions. I have a 300GB hard-drive separated into 3 partitions. While it does show SATA for my main hard-drive and my disk drive, it doesn't show the partitions. Is this typical? Do I have to us an OS-based tool to delete the partitions or can I delete using my BIOS?

I tried updating the BIOS through Asus's Update utility but it appears to be broken (connects/disconnects repeatedly). I used HWiNFO32 to get some information:

> BIOS Date: 06/30/10
>
> BIOS Version: 2103
>
> EFI BIOS: Not Capable

Tried to update but it directs me to biosagentsplus.com which wants $30 for the download (another question would be how to avoid them).

Comment: "While it does show SATA for my main hard-drive and my disk drive, it doesn't show the partitions. Is this typical?" YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you **cannot** view or edit partitions from BIOS. You need to boot into an operating system. It is easier if it has a gui though.

Get [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com). Burn it to cd/usb, and boot your computer to it. 
Mount the hd.

Please be careful, editing partitions can render your system unbootable. Backup your data before you change/adjust anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for BIOS to not show the partitions of your hard drive. BIOS stands for "basic input/output system," so it's what BIOS can do will not be enough to accomplish tasks such as deleting a partition. If you need to delete a partition, it needs to be done on an operating system such as Windows or Linux.